# a word for the existing state of affairs before you change something

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm sorry for the question being so vague, I really don't know what to use for this. The word I'm looking for isn't status quo and the only way I can explain it to you is:
When talking about opt-in organs, if you don't choose to opt out, the (dash) state is that your organs will be donated after your death.

Comment: Is default what you want?

Comment: Though the earlier question (obviously the title questions are duplicates) does not provide other answers, 'existing state of affairs' / 'current situation' / 'how things stand' are easily found in a search for 'status quo'  in [YourDictionary_thesaurus](https://thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/status-quo). 'Default state' is less usual in this situation.